# Impossible configuration in gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

I am banging my head on a wall with this one and getting nowhere. I hope that someone here has a clue or just confirm my impression that it's impossible to do.

I am using gitolite 2.3 on an internal repository to apply advanced ACLs. I have been asked to modify the configuration so that users in a special group, say `@projectX` are able to:

- push any change, including non fast-forward, on any branch whose name begins with `projectX-`;
- for other branches, they must be able to push only if the file is in the directory `/projectX` at the top level, otherwise they must be able only to pull/clone.

Now, giving them full permissions on "their" branches and clone/pull on any other is trivial, a rule like `RW+ projectX-.* = @projectX` will do.

In the same way, giving them full permissions on a path and pull/clone permissions otherwise is also easy (just a few rules).

I can't find a way to apply "both", so that the users retains full permissions on their branches and read-only permission on any other branch with the exception of "their" path.

I am starting to feel the smell of impossible... any clues?

Thanks in advance

`-- bronto`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be accomplished:

- The "conf" file (conf/gitolite.conf)

  - http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#what-does-a-rule-look-like
  - http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#refex

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.